# Mediawiki 1.16: Leaving timestamp in template

Tags: mediawiki

~~~~ is used to leave your timestamp with your name and date. I want to put this in a template so that whoever uses the template will have have the timestamp printed out as well.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible when substing the template. For example `~~<includeonly>~~</includeonly>` will display as ~~~~ when the template is transcluded normally, and as a timestamp when substed.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Technical_metadata) also may help and allows to format the timestamp more precisely:

- `{{REVISIONDAY}}`
- `{{REVISIONDAY2}}`
- `{{REVISIONMONTH}}`
- `{{REVISIONMONTH1}}`
- `{{REVISIONYEAR}}`
- `{{REVISIONTIMESTAMP}}`
- `{{REVISIONUSER}}`

And [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Technical_metadata_of_another_page) describes how to use the above magic words referring another pages.

Answer (score 0):

Not without rewriting some of the code I don't think. ~~~~ will always be changed by the parser into the signature, and not be saved in the wikitext as ~~~~